# How to contact a user?

Tags: support, comments, users

I'd like to thanks one user for some changes he made to one of my question, how can I do it?

I've done it trough the comments, but I'm not sure he will get my answer, am I wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the @-style comment replies, they'll be notified immediately if they are logged in or as soon as they next log in if they are not. See [How do @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) over on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) for more. Assuming you are referring to the edit on your first question, you *did it exactly right*! +1 for that!

You can also check out the user's profile page and see if they have included any contact info. Some folks include email or other contact info there which means it's OK (even expected) for you to contact them that way.

This site is explicitly (and often vehemently!) NOT a social networking site, so there isn't a private message system of any kind.

Comment: Thanks a lot yhw42 and thanks as well to @Iszi !

Comment: @tmow: You're very welcome and welcome to the site! (and FYI, I don't think Iszi was notified by that, since it only works on a post(a question or answer) that that user has _participated_ in. `:)`)

Comment: well, according to "How do @replies work" I would say yes, but the best way is to try it. @Iszi if you're there, knock once :-)

Comment: no answer, so you were right :-p

Comment: If there is no private message system of any kind, is it okay to offer a user to contact me by mail? (My mail address is in my profile). Just wondering how to best help somebody who is asking a lot of beginners questions, and is constantly being told that they are duplicate or too subjective.

Answer (score 2):

Comments, answers to questions, and pings in chat generate an alert to the user, via the "Inbox" counter next to the StackExchange link in the upper-left corner as well as the message icon next to their username in the top bar.

The only people with access to out-of-band contact information (i.e.: e-mail address) for users, are "diamond" moderators and site admins.